# ASP.NET MVC3 Web application not behaving the same once published on IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, iis-7.5

I have written an ASP.NET MVC3 Web application which runs perfectly inside the Visual Studio development web server and run on a specific IIS web server.

I have successfully published the same web application on another IIS web server. It runs well except for a strange behavior.

My controller actions returns the content without problem, but the layout page isn't rendered. I end up having only the content returned by the controller action.

What am I missing ?

Comment: make sure you reference the shared layout correctly or share layout chtml file is visible in your pages

Comment: Could be a permissions issue. Are you using HTTPS?

Comment: Shouldn't it return an error page if it couldn't access the layout file ? I got no error. I only get my partial view content without the layout around it.

Comment: maybe its the cache? have you tried ctrl + f5?

Comment: I was thinking it was a cache problem too. I hit CTRL+F5 but I've got the same behavior. Works perfectly in my dev environment but once on that IIS server, no layout page rendered, only my partial view content.

Comment: @SteveHémond try granting permissions to the user of the application pool to the entire directory. This happened to me before,and it was a security issue. The difference is I was using HTTPS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I bet you have hardcoded the urls to scripts and CSS in your view instead of using Url helpers. You wrote:

```
<link href="/Content/Site.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

instead of the correct way:

```
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Site.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

or you wrote:

```
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js"" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

instead of the correct way:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Now go ahead and search for all places where you have hardcoded urls like this and replace them with urls generated by helpers.

The reason why your site doesn't work when deployed in IIS is because in IIS there's a probably a virtual directory that you have to take into account. So the correct address is `http://example.com/myappname/content/site.css` whereas when running locally there's no such directory `http://localhost:1234/content/site.css`.

Comment: In fact, in my layout page, the jquery scripts were not referenced using the Url.Content helper. I've corrected that and it works perfectly. Thank you very much !